# Reference with no new lines breaks internal links

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, formatting, cross-referencing, hyperlink

I'm trying to use `natbib` and have the references in a paragraph, instead of a list with one reference per line. The example below achieves this goal, but it breaks internal links between the text and the bibliography (a clic on the reference in the text does not direct to the bibliography). The culprits are the commands between the `%biblio` comments.
Do you know why? And perhaps any insight on how to fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round,comma]{natbib}
%\setcitestyle{numbers, comma, open={(},close={)} }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{paralist}

%biblio
\let\olditem\item
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  \section*{\large \refname}
  \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax
  \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\olditem[$\bullet$]}%
  \inparaenum}{\endinparaenum}
%biblio

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

Hi \citep{wilde}

\lipsum[2]
Hi \citep{shore}
\lipsum[3]
Hi \citep{springer}
\lipsum[4-10]

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round,comma]{natbib}
%\setcitestyle{numbers, comma, open={(},close={)} }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{paralist}

%biblio
\makeatletter
\def\NAT@anchor#1#2{%
 \hfilneg\hyper@natanchorstart{#1\@extra@b@citeb}%
 \textbullet
 \hyper@natanchorend
}%
\makeatother
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  \section*{\large \refname}
  \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax
  \inparaenum}{\endinparaenum}
%biblio

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

Hi \citep{wilde}

\lipsum[2] Hi \citep{shore} \lipsum[3] Hi \citep{springer} \lipsum[4-10] 

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\end{document}
```